# How to update data by using id in php & mysql? I have tried but data is not updated

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I try to update data by using that program but data is not updated in the table. It is showing that data is updated successfully but data is not updated. When I try to execute that program data is deleted. how can I update data. I am attaching image of code.

[image]

Comment: **Don't post image of your code**, rather post the code itself. And be more specific with your problem. Please check - [ask].

Comment: I have tried but the code is not uploading

Comment: You definitely should check - [ask]

Comment: You need to post the code, select it and click `ctrl+k`, I don't believe that the system rejected your code

Answer (score 0):

When you editing(in get request) the record then you can set your `edit_id` in a hidden field may be called id and when you are updating the record you get details of each field using `$_POST['field_name']` then you can get id also using `$_POST` and then pass this id in the update query.

I hope this will work...!